# SQL query only show max value - how to do that?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Sorry for my bad English.

```
SELECT   
    siparisler.siparis_tarihi, MAX(ADET), urunler.urun_ismi
FROM 
    SIPARISLER,
    URUNLER,
    MUSTERILER,
    SIPARIS_DETAY
WHERE     
    SIPARISLER.SIPARISID = SIPARIS_DETAY.SIPARISID
    AND URUNLER.URUN_ID = SIPARIS_DETAY.URUN_ID
    AND MUSTERILER.MUSTERI_ID = SIPARISLER.MUSTERI_ID  
GROUP BY  
    urunler.urun_ismi ,siparis_tarihi 
ORDER BY 
    siparis_tarihi;
```

This is my oracle SQL code and this is the result

[image]

How can I show only max value like this:

[image]

Every date I can show max row thanks

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and order the result by `max(adet)` descending and then select the top row from the result using `rownum = 1`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT siparisler.siparis_tarihi,
                    max(adet),
                    urunler.urun_ismi
                    FROM siparis_detay
                         INNER JOIN siparisler
                                    ON siparisler.siparisid = siparis_detay.siparisid
                         INNER JOIN urunler
                                    ON urunler.urun_id = siparis_detay.urun_id
                         INNER JOIN musteriler
                                    ON musteriler.musteri_id = siparisler.musteri_id
                    GROUP BY urunler.urun_ismi,
                             siparisler.siparis_tarihi
                    ORDER BY max(adet) DESC) x
       WHERE rownum = 1;
```

You should also use explicit join syntax for better readability.

---

Edit:

The above is an answer to the original question. Below addresses the comment.

Try to use `row_number()` to assign row numbers to each row partitioned by the date in descending order of the maximum `adet` and then select only the ones where the row number is equal to 1.

```
SELECT y.siparis_tarihi,
       y.adet,
       y.urun_ismi
       FROM (SELECT x.siparis_tarihi,
                    x.adet,
                    x.urun_ismi,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY x.siparis_tarihi
                                       ORDER BY x.adet DESC) r
                    FROM (SELECT siparisler.siparis_tarihi,
                                 max(adet) adet,
                                 urunler.urun_ismi
                                 FROM siparis_detay
                                      INNER JOIN siparisler
                                                 ON siparisler.siparisid = siparis_detay.siparisid
                                      INNER JOIN urunler
                                                 ON urunler.urun_id = siparis_detay.urun_id
                                      INNER JOIN musteriler
                                                 ON musteriler.musteri_id = siparisler.musteri_id
                                 GROUP BY urunler.urun_ismi,
                                          siparisler.siparis_tarihi) x) y
       WHERE y.r = 1;
```

That shows only one record for each date. If you want to show all rows with the maximum for a date on a tie, replace `row_number()` with `rank()`.

Comment: this is wrong result Man verry thanks but ı  want to every date ı can show max row value
example 01-01-2018 limon 20  after  02 01 2018 maracuja etc after your code result is  01-03-2018  30 h.cevizi but this is wrong value

Comment: @UzayIlıca: Have a look at my edit. Maybe that helps?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use the `keep` functionality for aggregation.  This does exactly what you want:

```
SELECT s.siparis_tarihi, MAX(ADET),
       MAX(u.urun_ismi) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ADET DESC)
FROM SIPARISLER s JOIN
     URUNLER u
     ON s.SIPARISID = u.SIPARISID JOIN
     SIPARIS_DETAY sd
     ON u.URUN_ID = sd.URUN_ID JOIN
     MUSTERILER m
     ON m.MUSTERI_ID = s.MUSTERI_ID
GROUP BY s.siparis_tarihi 
ORDER BY s.siparis_tarihi;
```

Notes:

- This uses proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- This uses simple table aliases.  These make the table easier to write and to read.